# Phonegap app wont play audio

Tags: android, cordova

I'm making a app with several audio files, but it won't play on the phone. It won't work even without `/android_asset/www/`.

Here's my code:

```
<script>
    var at_du_bruger_det = new Audio('/android_asset/www/sound/at_du_bruger_det.wav');
</script>
<div class="swipebox portfolio-wide-item" onclick="at_du_bruger_det.play();">
    <h3>At du bruger det</h3>
    <p>Tryk for at afspille</p>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
    <img class="responsive-image" src="images/at_du_bruger_det.jpg" alt="img">
</div>
```

I've added the `org.apache.cordova.media` plugin to the config file.

Comment: I would recommend you to try Intel's XDK platform, it seems to be more supportive and stable for cross-platform apps.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [Cordova Media plugin documentation](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-media#mediaplay), you can see that a Media object is required:

```
// Play audio
function playAudio(url) {
    // Play the audio file at url
    var my_media = new Media(url,
        // success callback
        function () {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
        },
        // error callback
        function (err) {
            console.log("playAudio():Audio Error: " + err);
        }
    );
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
}
```

Comment: How do i implement it?